# Python plotting a function after derivation

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

Could you lend a hand. We are trying to plot a function after a derivation but receive an error message.

`ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (20,) and (1,)`

We believe the issue is that the function is not being calculated with the values in the second function and are not able to pinpoint the issue.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
#from sympy import *

x = sp.symbols('x')
y_funktion = x**5-5*x**4-30*x**3+110*x**2+29*x-105

def funktionenErstellen(y_funktion):    
    y_funktion_ableitung = sp.diff(y_funktion, x)
    y_funktion_stammfunktion = sp.integrate(y_funktion, x)
    print('Funktion:', y_funktion)
    print('Ableitung:', y_funktion_ableitung)
    return [y_funktion_ableitung, y_funktion_stammfunktion]
    

def plotFunktionen(funktion):
    x = np.arange(-10, 10, 1.0)  
    plt.xlim(-7.5, 9)
    plt.ylim(-900,900)
    plt.grid()
    # Plot the points using matplotlib
    plt.xlabel('X-Achse')
    plt.ylabel('Y-Achse')
    print('funktion:',  funktion)
    plt.plot(x, funktion, color = "r", label = 'Funktion')
    #plt.plot(x, y_funktion_ableitung, color = "g", label = 'Ableitung')
    #plt.plot(x, y_funktion_stammfunktion, color = "b", label = 'Stammfunktion')
    plt.legend()

[y_funktion_ableitung, y_funktion_stammfunktion] = funktionenErstellen(y_funktion)

plotFunktionen(y_funktion)
plotFunktionen(y_funktion_ableitung)
plotFunktionen(y_funktion_stammfunktion)
```

Comment: When you call `plotFunktionen(y_funktion)`, you are trying to plot `plt.plot(x, funktion, ...)` with `x` a numpy array containing 20 elements and `funktion` a SymPy expression. You need to **evaluate** this expression, store the result in an array (say `y`) then `plt.plot(x, y, ...)`.

Comment: You can either plot via sympy (`sp.plot(...)`), or convert `funktion` from sympy to a numpy function via `sp.lambdify(...)` and then call that function on `x`. Note that you are complicating things a lot by using the same variable name `x` twice, which hinders the necessary access to the sympy version of `x` inside the plot function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers @Guimoute and @JohanC
We managed to get it running.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x')
y_funktion = x**5-5*x**4-30*x**3+110*x**2+29*x-105
def funktionenErstellen(y_funktion):    
    y_funktion_ableitung = sp.diff(y_funktion, x)
    y_funktion_stammfunktion = sp.integrate(y_funktion, x)
    print('Funktion:\t\t', y_funktion)
    print('Ableitung:\t\t', y_funktion_ableitung)
    print('Stammfunktion:\t', y_funktion_stammfunktion)
    return [y_funktion_ableitung, y_funktion_stammfunktion]
    
def plotFunktionen(funktion, typ, color):
    
    x_wert = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.2)
    f = sp.lambdify(x, funktion)
    f = f(x_wert)
    plt.xlim(-7.5, 9)
    plt.ylim(-900,900)
    plt.grid()
    
    # Plot the points using matplotlib
    plt.xlabel('X-Achse')
    plt.ylabel('Y-Achse')
    plt.plot(x_wert, f, color = color, label = typ)

[y_funktion_ableitung, y_funktion_stammfunktion] = funktionenErstellen(y_funktion)
plotFunktionen(y_funktion, 'Funktion', 'r')
plotFunktionen(y_funktion_ableitung, 'Ableitung', 'g')
plotFunktionen(y_funktion_stammfunktion, 'Stammfunktion', 'b')
plt.legend()
```